# I'm confused on using @extend to inherit another class with SCSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

First off, let me say that I've only used a little bit of LESS and I'm now trying to pick up on SCSS since Bootstrap 4 is written in SCSS. I'm trying to convert an existing Bootstrap 3 with LESS over to Bootstrap 4 with SCSS.

What I'm looking to do is to inherit Bootstrap's .btn and .btn-default values into my own class called .menu-item. I was able to do that with the following code with LESS. This allows me to control how I want the menu items to look with just one class.

```
.menu-item {
    .btn;
    .btn-default;
    color: @header-text-color;
}
```

So, from the videos I've seen about SCSS I would use @extends but I'm not getting the same effects as I did with LESS. The buttons don't seem to change color when I hoover and I'm trying to align them to the right of a Bootstrap grid using text-right but they are still left justified.

This might be due to the difference in BS3 vs BS4 but I'm mostly wanting to make sure that I'm inheriting values correctly using SCSS or should I be doing something else for inheritance?

This is my SCSS version:

```
.menu-item{
    @extend .btn;
    @extend .btn-default;
    color: $header-text-color;
}
```

This is how I'm using it in my _Layout.cshtml page.

```
<div class="col-md-6 text-right">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Schedule")" class="menu-item">Schedule</a>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "LogOut")" class="menu-item">Log Out</a>
    </div>
</div>
```